# APK made with Gradle doesn't include file

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk, android-build

In my Android project in Android Studio (migrated from eclipse), in the java source tree, I have a package with a plain text config-file (with no suffix). This file is not inlcuded in the generated APK.

What to do? How to change the build.gradle file so this file will be included? When I look inside APK made with eclipse, the file is there, but not with studio.

The file is expected to be in that path - it is used by third party jar located in the appModuleB

I have a structure like this:

```
 -Project-A
 --appModuleA
 ---build.gradle
 ---build
 ---src
 ----main
 -----java
 ------com
 -------packageA
 --------config-file  <<<<<
 -------packageB
 --------sourcesB..
 ...
 --build.gradle
 --appModuleB
 ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try specifying main.resources.srcDirs in your gradle file

Comment: how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

from google's gradle page

sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src/java']
        main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/resources']
    }

Comment: I tried to add it in the appModuleA, doesn't work. And I don't have any src/resources folder.

Comment: This was just an example, you can set it to src folder itself. I was just wondering if setting it explicity is required. It was not required in ADT though.

Comment: Resource files should be put into `src/main/resources`. No need to reconfigure anything.

Comment: Actually as I mentioned, the config file is expected by a third party jar to be in the main/java/com/packageA direcotry. So this is not an option.

Comment: Give it a try (`src/main/resources/com/packageA`), and you'll see that it works. (Correctly written Java code accesses resources by package, not by directory.) If it doesn't, something else is wrong.